# cURL request - unauthorized

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to send a cURL request to https://api.powerbike.pl/ to log in and get an XML but all I'm getting is

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

This is what I've tried

```
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$usernamePassword = 'Basic '.$username.':'.$password;
$basic = base64_encode($usernamePassword);
$loginUrl = 'https://api.powerbike.pl/';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "content-type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8",
    "Authorization: $basic"
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.powerbike.pl/xml/product/categories');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

$content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I see you have spaces in username and password . Maybe it is reason ?)

Comment: Edited the question. That's not the issue unfortunately.

Comment: if it is possible can you give me real password and user example for checking personally ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not authorized to give out that kind of information.

Comment: Did you intend this to be a GET request or a POST? You have both `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");`

Comment: First I need to log in (POST) and then get the XML (GET). Is this not the way to do it?

Comment: @Lendzmianos  No need to login.  Why are you getting xml rather than json?  JSON is very easy to work with in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this:

```
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$usernamePassword = 'Basic '.$username.':'.$password;
$basic = base64_encode($usernamePassword);
$loginUrl = 'https://api.powerbike.pl/';
```

Try these options:
curl will do the base64 encoding and add the `content-type:basic` header

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,"$username:$password");
```

Remove this header:

```
"Authorization: $basic"
```

This might work `"content-type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8"`
You can also try `"content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"`
The content type does not specify anything about what you receive only what you are sending.

That is telling the server that your request is in an XML format.  Its not.
And the $basic is incorrect.  You could use `"$username:$password"`.

Do not use this, as it required a GET

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

Do not use this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

That will return the response header in your `$content`.  You do not want that.

I tried this and the request header looked correct.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.powerbike.pl/xml/product/categories');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

echo $response;
echo "\n\n\nheader out: \n" . curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
```

The request header looked like this:

```
GET /xml/product/categories HTTP/1.1
Host: api.powerbike.pl
Authorization: Basic cGF0cmljazphc3dkO2twZmdqaQ==
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/xml
```

For your final version this should work fine:

```
$header = [];
$header[] = 'Content-Type: application/xml';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.powerbike.pl/xml/product/categories');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

Comment: @Lendzmianos I know this stuff is not easy as I once struggled with it.  I'm old (67) and do not want to die not having shared what I know with others.  I am very glad that I helped.